# Magento : showing sub sub categories in same order as in admin backend tree structure

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I using Magento 1.7.2, and am showing a list of sub categories and sub-sub categories, from a current category. My problem is that the sub-sub categories do not respect the same order as in the admin backend tree structure. It looks like they are being ordered via their id, from smalled id number to highest. I would need them to show as they are ordered in the admin backend. Here is my current code:

```
<?php 
$currCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
$parentname = $currCat->getName();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($currCat->getEntityId());
$subcats = $currCat->getChildren();

$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
echo '<h2 class="titleCat"><strong>'.$parentname.'</strong></h2>';
?>

<?php 
$currCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
$parentname = $currCat->getName();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($currCat->getEntityId());
$subcats = $currCat->getChildren();

$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
echo '<h2 class="titleCat"><strong>'.$parentname.'</strong></h2>';
?>

<!-- We list sub sub categories -->
<div class="colLeftNav">
<ul class="colLeftSubCats">
<?php
foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
if($_category->getIsActive()) {
$sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
echo '<div class="subMainCat"><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="Show products "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a></div>';
foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
{
$_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
echo '<li class="subCat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="show products "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
}
}
}
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am pretty much stuck here and have no clue how to resolve this. Any help would be really appreciated...!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$cat_id = 10;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($cat_id, 0, true, true);

foreach ($collection as $cat) {
    echo $cat->getId().' '.$cat->getPosition().' '.$cat->getName().'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: What are the extra parameters in getCategories?

Comment: * param int $parent
         * param int $recursionLevel
         * param bool $sorted
         * param bool $asCollection
         * param bool $toLoad

Comment: That is very useful to know.